# Can’t boot into MacOS from Windows(Bootcamp)

Tags: macos, windows, bootcamp, imac, bootable-disk

When pressing the <kbd>option</kbd> during startup, MacOS isn’t shown as an option to boot into.

Using the tray in win10 to “Restart in MacOS” also doesn’t work. It just restarts back into Windows 10.

[image]

It is an iMac 27" 5K 2017 model, running macOS 12.1. And in the windows side, it is running Windows 10 Pro Version 21H2.

Below is a screenshot showing how the disk is partitioned from within Windows.

[image]

Below is output showing the internal drives after running `diskutil list` in macOS Internet Recovery.

[image]

A more complete screenshot can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQykF.jpg).

I followed the steps posted. It seems it was disk1 this time so I used disk1 in when executing the commands.

[image]

Reinstalling also doesn’t show the mac drive (about 800gb), so I am currently unable to reinstall as well.

[image]

This is the disk utility showing the drives.
Below shows what I believe to be the macOS drive, which is currently unmounted so I am unable to boot into macOS or even select the drive for reinstalling macOS.

[image]

And here below is the startup disk selection.

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot showing how the disk is partitioned (from within Windows)?

Comment: Do you know the model year of the Mac? Do you know which version of Windows and macOS is installed? Can you boot to macOS Internet Recovery and post the output from the command `diskutil list`?

Comment: Hi @nohillside https://imgur.com/a/bhotMuq
I'm sorry I wasn't sure how uploading a picture worked.

Comment: Hello @DavidAnderson!
It's an iMac 27" 5K 2017 model, running macOS 12.1.
And in the windows side, it is running Windows 10 Pro Version 21H2.

Comment: Here is the list from Internet Recovery
https://imgur.com/a/i3FQUuY

Comment: You can add the pictures the same way you added the first one. There is an edit link at the bottom of the post.

Comment: Possibly, the ID for the first partition on `disk2`  was changed from `EE` to `06`.

Answer (score 1):

One possability is the ID for the first partition in the MBR table on `disk2` was changed from `EE` to `06`. Here, I assume `disk2` is the SSD part of an internal Fusion drive arrangement.

You could make the following entries to change the ID to `EE`. You will need to boot to macOS Internet Recovery.

> Note: Before making the entries given below, you should first enter the command `diskutil list internal`, then check to see if `disk2` is still the identifier of the same drive shown in your posted images.

```
fdisk -e /dev/disk2
s 1
ee
w
q
```

Afterwards, post the output from the commands below.

```
fdisk /dev/disk2
gpt -r show /dev/disk2
diskutil list internal
```

You many need to make more entries after posting the output.

### Update 1

Based on the output posted after changing the ID to `ee`, I can see you do not a valid GUID Partition Table (GPT) stored in internal SSD (`disk2`). Your model Mac is suppose to have a Fusion drive arrangement, where there would be an APFS container consisting of an APFS partition from the internal HDD and an APFS partition from the internal SSD. Since the firmware can only find an APFS partition on the internal HDD, none of the APFS volumes can be mounted and thus macOS can not boot. If you have a backup on needed files, you would probably be better off reinstalling macOS and Windows.

### Update 2

Before attempting to reinstall  macOS, you will need to rebuild a Fusion container. Below are the commands to enter.

> Note: Before making the entries given below, you should first enter the command `diskutil list internal`, then check to see if `disk0` and `disk2` are still the identifiers of the same drives shown in your posted images. For instance, `disk0` should be 1.0 TB in size and `disk2` should be 28.0 GB in size.

```
diskutil apfs deleteContainer -force disk0s2 Temp1
diskutil erasedisk jhfs+ Temp2 gpt disk2
diskutil apfs create disk2s2 disk0s2 "Macintosh HD"
```

If you successfully reinstall macOS, then post a comment and I will add steps to remove the `OSXRESERVED` volume and add the free space to the APFS container.

Comment: I was wondering if I will lose my data if I go forward with the steps mentioned in Update 2

Comment: You will lose any data in the macOS volume. The Boot Camp volume should remain unchanged. Still, to be safe, you should always have a backup of important data.

Comment: Hello Is there any way to make a backup? Since the drive appears to be “unmounted”

Comment: I do not know of any way you could mount the APFS volumes where macOS was stored.

Comment: There is no way to backup the data of the macOS part?

Comment: I won’t be able to keep data form MacOS?